# IPython won't capture some command outputs (e.g., ack)

Tags: shell, ipython

I don't understand why IPython does not assign the result of some system command to python variables. This seems to constantly happen to me to the [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/) and [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) executables

For example, the following command produces output:

```
In [1]: !ack --nocolor foo
bar
1:foo
```

However, whenever I save that result to a variable, I get an empty output

```
In [2]: out=!ack --nocolor foo

In [3]: out
Out[3]: []
```

I get this problem even when I try all sorts of hacks:

```
In [4]: out=!ack --nocolor foo > tmp; sleep 1; cat tmp

In [5]: out
Out[5]: []
```

In fact, `tmp` is empty in the last case, which suggests that the output capture messes up with these commands.

Does anyone how if this is a problem with IPython or ack/ag, or simply my misunderstanding of how IPython should behave here?

Comment: `out=!ack --thpppt` works!

Comment: `!ack ... > tmp` followed by `out=!cat tmp` (separate line) works for me.  Evidently there's some incompatibility between how `out=!...` collects the output and how `ack` produces it, but discovering that may require digging into the code of one or the other.

Comment: After some digging and experimenting I've deduced that you need to add a `--nofilter` flag to your `ack` command.

Comment: I don't have problems with `out = !ag ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've deduced that `out = !cmd` uses `%sx`.  This is different from how `!cmd` is run (see docs for `%sw` and `%system`).

`%sx` goes through several layers of functions, and ends up calling

```
# import IPython
IPython.utils._process_common.process_handler
```

Its code is similar to the `subprocess` call that @Elliott Frisch uses in his deleted answer:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ack --nocolor foo", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
```

I abstracted the `process_handler` code in:

```
def cmd1(astr='ack --nocolor 15 *.txt'):
    callback = lambda p: p.communicate()
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
    shell = True
    close_fds = True
    executable = None
    p = subprocess.Popen(astr, 
                         shell=shell,
                         executable=executable,
                         #stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=stderr,
                         close_fds=close_fds,
                         )
    out = callback(p)
    return out, p.returncode
```

This works:

```
In [40]: cmd1()
Out[40]: 
((b'stack53269737.txt:2:11 12 13 14 15 16\ntest.txt:3:11\t12 13 14 15\ntest1.txt:5:  0.054181,  0.506962,  0.315159,  0.653104\n',
  None),
 0)
```

But if I uncomment the `stdin` line, it fails:

```
In [42]: cmd1()
Out[42]: ((b'', None), 1)
```

So it's the

```
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
```

parameter that causes the `ack` call to fail.  It doesn't cause problems with other common shell commands like `ls` or `grep`.

---

`ack` help has:

```
 --[no]filter               Force ack to treat standard input as a pipe
                            (--filter) or tty (--nofilter)
```

Adding `--nofilter` to my commands (`--nocolor` isn't needed with this redirection):

```
In [50]: cmd1('ack --nofilter 15 *.txt')
Out[50]: 
((b'stack53269737.txt:2:11 12 13 14 15 16\ntest.txt:3:11\t12 13 14 15\ntest1.txt:5:  0.054181,  0.506962,  0.315159,  0.653104\n',
  None),
 0)

In [51]: out = !ack --nofilter 15 *.txt
In [52]: out
Out[52]: 
['stack53269737.txt:2:11 12 13 14 15 16',
 'test1.txt:5:  0.054181,  0.506962,  0.315159,  0.653104',
 'test.txt:3:11\t12 13 14 15']
```

So that's the key - force `ack` to ignore the piped input (though I don't fully understand the details).

Comment: Thanks so much, @hpaulj, this is very helpful! So, from what I understand, when we run `out = !ack foo`, this roughly gets translated to `cat /dev/stdin | ack foo`, which unfortunately behaves very differently than `ack foo`. So, it would be nice if one could document that iPython pipes in the standard input!

Comment: By the way, ack's man page (v.2.24) also got me confused: "If files are not specified for searching, either on the command line or piped in with the "-x" option, ack delves into subdirectories selecting files for searching.".This is not correct: `ack` actually tries to search in the STDIN if it's piped in.

Comment: I'm no expert on this subprocess and shell stuff, but I suspect `ipython` is using the input pipe to allow for ^c breaks.  `process_handler` has a `try` block to flush and terminate subprocess.