# Alternating Shell and Python commands at Jupyter on the same line

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

How can I do a chain of python and shell commands at the same line, alternating?
Is there a way of embedding a magic within a Python expression?

For example:

```
var = !date +%s <<command to stop magic execution>> [0]
```

How I'm doing it now:

```
var = !date +%s
var = var[0]
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use Jupyter extensions rather than native Python syntax (such as `subprocess`-based invocation)?

Comment: BTW, for the specific example of `date -s`, you don't need a shell for it at all -- Python can give you UNIX time in seconds itself. `var = time.time()` (after `import time`), and you're done (maybe casting to `int` if you only want an integer rather than a floating-point value).

Comment: When using `!` (or other magics) all the rest of the line is handled by the magic,  That is, the strings are passed to the magic.  So, no, there isn't a way of flagging the end of the command, and the start of Python processing.  What you are doing now is the right way; don't fight it!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, no, there's not compelling reason rather than the fact that it improves readability. Again, the date command was just an example.

Comment: @hpaulj Are you sure that there's no way to stop the 'Jupyter's magic commands' execution rather than using another line? Are there some document showing this? If this is true, I think we can close this because I'm not trying to find other ways.

Comment: Another way to put the question - is there a way of embedding a magic within a Python expression?

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent that works in all Python interpreters, whether or not Jupyter is active, would be:

```
import subprocess
def shell(args):
    return subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].split('\n')

var = shell('date +%s')[0]
```

...that said, for the specific use case, you don't need it:

```
import time
var = str(int(time.time()))
```

will calculate the same value with far less overhead. (And if you don't *want* the side effects such as rounding to the nearest second or converting to a string, the needed changes will be obvious).

Comment: I appreciate your way forward but I wanted the Jupyter way to do it.

Comment: Also, the date scenario was just an example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're assuming that there **is** a Jupyter way to do it. That's not a well-founded assumption: Jupyter's "magic" either operates on a whole line or a whole cell; it doesn't embed itself at the language's AST layer, so it can't replace arbitrary subexpressions.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that. If there isn't any way to stop a magic operation I think we can close this. Can you prove that it's not possible?

Comment: I explored what's happening with `out = !...` in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908761/ipython-wont-capture-some-command-outputs-e-g-ack.  It actually is a `%sx` magic, which you can examine with `%sx??`